# Stored procedure to add a new order which takes a list of products

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2019

I have 3 tables: `Products`, `Orders` and `OrderDetails`.

**Products**

| ProductID | ProductName | QtyInStock | CurrentPrice |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Adidas Shoes | 10 | 100.00 |
| 2 | Nike Shoes | 10 | 100.00 |

**Orders**

| OrderID | OrderDate | DeliveryAddress |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 27-04-22 | 1 Smith St. |
| 2 | 27-04-22 | 8 Smith St. |

**OrderDetails**

| OrderID | ProductID | QtyOrdered |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 |

I have already created a stored procedure for creating a new `Product` which is obviously added to the `Products` table, however, I need to create the following stored procedure for adding a new `Order`:

- Within the stored procedure, you allow a list of products to be passed together with the order number
- When the quantity is ordered, please decrease the `Quantity in Stock` in the `Product` table

For example:

- Order:

  - **Order:** 123
  - **Order Date:** 2022-01-01 09:02:32.232
  - **Delivery Address:** 1 Smith St, Melbourne
- Order Items:

  - ProductId: 1, Quantity: 10
  - ProductId: 6, Quantity: 1
  - ProductId: 8, Quantity: 18

I am also required to use a table-valued parameter to complete this stored procedure.

I guess the question I don't know the answer to is how to pass a list of key-value pairs when executing the stored procedure for creating the new order.

Edit: My current attempt
Firstly, sorry if this is horribly wrong but here's my current attempt for those asking:

```
CREATE TYPE OrderInfo as TABLE
(
    OrderID int,
    OrderDate date,
    DeliveryAddress varchar(100),
    ProductID int,
    Quantity int
)

CREATE PROC OrderData
@OrderTVP OrderInfo READONLY
AS
SELECT * FROM @OrderTVP

DECLARE OrderVarParam AS OrderInfo

INSERT INTO @OrderVarParam
    INSERT INTO Orders values(OrderID, OrderDate, DeliveryAddress)
    INSERT INTO OrderDetails values (OrderID, ProductID, Quantity)

EXEC OrderData @OrderVarParam
```

Edit 2: I mistakenly included CurrentPrice in the Orders table so I removed it for sake of clarification for future reference.

Comment: You need to create a user defined table type, and then define your table valued parameter as being of this type (with the keyword READONLY) . To call the SP you then create a variable of this type, and insert the values, using the same syntax as for a table.

Comment: I've spent the majority of today looking at TVPs. It's for a job. Maybe this isn't thw right place to post the question. But my previous roles haven't been SQL heavy so I'm trying to figure out the solution to it.

Comment: So after reading about TVP's, what did you try?

Comment: I've tried doing that to how I've understood it. The bit I really don't understand is when I'm going to execute the SP then how I can add a list of products. So "exec sp_InsertANewProduct 5, 24-07-22, '1 Smith St.' [ProductID, Quantity][ProductID, Quantity] - I just don't really know how I'd execute the SP and add a list as parameter. But I'm guessing the list would be something to do with a TVP?

Comment: @JordyNelson How are you invoking the proposed procedure? Directly from application code via `SqlCommand` (with `CommandType.StoredProcedure`) or from another procedure or statement-batch?

Comment: Rather than trying to describe your attempted code in a comment, post your actual attempted code in the body of the question, even if it's incomplete or doesn't work. It will give us a clearer picture of what you're missing.

Comment: Please show your current attempt

Comment: Did you read my comment? To make it more clear, once you have created an appropriate table type (call it eg OrderListType), you then declare a variable (`declare @orderlist OrderListType;`). You then go `INSERT INTO @orderlist VALUES (1, 10),...` and finally you pass this variable (@orderlist) to your stored procedure.  BTW don't use a sp_ prefix in your procedure.name. Microsoft has reserved its use

Comment: Read Erland's discussion of [table-valued parameters](https://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2008.html). You don't specifically mention which coding environment - which is a significant factor in a "how do I ..." question. Simple searching will find many tutorials that are directly written to your implementation environment.

Comment: @SMor As far as I understand the task, this is all purely within TSQL. He doesn't seem to be required to call it from outside.

Comment: Correct, I'm not required to do an external call. Simply validate it inside on SSMS and generate a script to show my workings per say. I have also posted my current attempt

Comment: Your type only needs to have ProductId and Quantity, as the rest of the information is common and can be passed as normal parameters. Your procedure will then need to insert into the Orders and OrderDetails tables, using the data in these parameters.  It will also need to update the Products table.

Comment: It is also important to know if the various IDs are `IDENTITY` as that affects how you do the inserts

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track, but you've got a ways to go yet.

You said this question was "for a job", which sounds like a sort of "take home exam" for a job interview, which creates an ethical problem for people who can help: If we just give you the answer, then we are in some sense helping you to "lie" about your actual level of knowledge, which is presumably what the question is supposed to be checking. Meta discussion on this site generally seems to prefer a "help, but don't solve" approach.

I also have questions about the "schema" you have included in your question.

For example, your `Orders` table includes a `DeliveryAddress` column, with sample data that looks like some kind of `DeliveryAddressId`. But there's no `Addresses` table.

Also, your `Orders` table has a `CurrentPrice` column. But `CurrentPrice` appears to be something that applies to a `Product`. If an `Order` can have multiple `OrderDetails`, and each `OrderDetail` can refer to a different `Product`, how can an `Order` have a `CurrentPrice`? Is it meant to be the sum of prices on the lines, perhaps?

But I'm going to continue without answers to these questions, because I'm not going to give you an entire solution and don't need all of the details to do that. I'm going to "help, but not solve".

So, let's go through what you've got:

```sql
CREATE TYPE OrderInfo as TABLE
(
    OrderID int,
    OrderDate date,
    DeliveryAddress varchar(100),
    ProductID int,
    Quantity int
)
```

You are going to create one order.

That order will have a single `OrderId`, and `OrderDate`, and `DeliveryAddress`. But it can have multiple `OrderDetails`, with each `OrderDetail` having its own `Product` and `Quantity`.

If you pass the `OrderId`, `OrderDate` and `DeliveryAddress` in the table valued parameter, you will be passing these same values multiple times (once per required `OrderDetail`), which is unnecessary.

Only the `ProductId` and `Quantity` need to be columns in the table valued parameter. The other three values can be passed as scalar parameters when we get to the procedure.

This also implies a better name for our type. It's not just "order information in general". it's specifically information about the products on the order. I think `OrderedProducts` would be a good name for the type.

Per Jonathan's comment below you have specified a `Date` datatype for the `OrderDate`, but your question implies you want to be able to have a `datetime`. We'll fix that in the scalar parameter.

Looking at the next bit:

```sql
CREATE PROC OrderData
@OrderTVP OrderInfo READONLY
AS
SELECT * FROM @OrderTVP
```

In your question you said "I don't know how to pass a list of key-value pairs when executing the stored procedure", but you've actually got that part pretty much right as described above, except for the unnecessary columns. Don't think of the table valued parameter as "key value pairs". We're in a relational database here. It's a table.

Do you get to name the procedure, or have you been told to use the name `OrderData`? That's a bad name in my opinion. Name things after what they are (as per the `OrderedProducts`), or what they do. What does this procedure do, in business terms? It creates an order.

Technical point: You currently have all of this in "one script", at least as far as the way you've written it in your question is concerned. if you tried to execute this whole script as a deployment it would fail, because `create procedure` has to be the first statement in a batch, and you have no batch terminator after your `create type` statement.

```sql
create type OrderedProducts as table ( /* fill in the correct columns here */ );

-- you need a batch terminator to make this a deployable script
go

-- Get into the habit of using "create or alter" for procedures, functions and views
create or alter procedure CreateOrder 
(
   @orderId int, 
   @orderDate datetime, 
   @DeliveryAddress varchar(100),
   @OrderedProducts OrderedProducts readonly
) as begin
   -- typically good practise to include this at the top of a procedure
   -- unless you have a very specific reason not to
   set xact_abort, nocount on; 

   -- do work here

end
```

From this point on you haven't made much of an attempt. You need to:

- `update` some rows in the `Products` table, and
- `insert` a new row into the `Orders` table, and
- `insert` some rows into the `OrderDetails` table

And you're probably going to want to do it *in that order*. Why? Well, think about what happens if two users are both placing orders for the same product at the same time. You only have a limited amount of stock available. If one user consumes all remaining quantity, is there any point trying to create the rows in `Orders` and `OrderDetails` for the second user?

But you're not doing any of those things. Clearly you do have some idea how to do an `insert`, because you're inserting into the table valued parameter in your posted code!

Perhaps you are struggling with the idea of inserting or updating multiple rows at the same time? But you can find information on how to do this on the net pretty easily.

What if your procedure successfully does the `update` of the `Products` table, but then fails when trying to do the `insert` into the `Orders` table? You want everything in this procedure to complete together, or you want everything to fail together. You need to create a "unit of work". You need a transaction, and some way of handling failure appropriately:

```sql
create type OrderedProducts as table ( /* ... */ );
go

-- Get into the habit of using "create or alter" for procedures, functions and views
create or alter procedure CreateOrder 
(
   @orderId int, 
   @orderDate datetime, 
   @DeliveryAddress varchar(100),
   @OrderedProducts OrderedProducts readonly
) as begin
   -- typically good practise to include this at the top of a procedure
   -- unless you have a very specific reason not to
   set xact_abort, nocount on; 

   begin try

      begin tran;

      update p
      set    /* you need to change the quantity here */
      from   Products         p
      join   @OrderedProducts op  on  -- ... fill in the rest

      insert Orders (OrderId, OrderDate, /* etc */ )
      values ( /* ... */ );

      insert OrderDetails ( /* ... */)
      select /* ... */
      from   @OrderedProducts op
      join   Products         p on  /* ... you need to get the price */

      commit;
      return 0;

   end try begin catch

      -- any kind of error handling you want to do, 
      -- but explicitly rollback juuuuust in case someone removes the xact_abort later!
      if (@@trancount > 0) rollback;    

   end catch
end
```

For infomration on patterns for error handling, I know of no better source of information than [this series of articles](https://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html#introduction) by Erland Sommarskog.

Comment: Excellent answer IMHO. However @orderDate should be a datetime, as the OP wants to pass 2022-01-01 09:02:32.232.

Comment: Honestly blown away by the level of detail in your response so thanks very much for that. To address the morality of it being for a job interview. It's a job that I'm proabably ultimately unqualified for given my lack of industry experience with SQL so even completing one SP on my own was a pretty proud moment for me. 

I do completely get that I just can't get the answer and I'm willing to take the responses I have been given here and work it out on my way, because after all problem solving is a part of the job.

Answer (score 0):

You only need a TVP for the items/details, not the whole order.

- The TVP should have a primary key. The other columns should probably also be `NOT NULL`.
- `CurrentPrice` should be part of the `OrderDetails` table, not `Orders`.
- Use a transaction to ensure correct rollback.
- `Products` needs a joined update.
- Sounds like you want `datetime` not `date` for `OrderDate`.

```sql
CREATE TYPE dbo.OrderInfo AS TABLE
(
    ProductID int PRIMARY KEY,
    Quantity int NOT NULL
);
```

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROC dbo.InsertOrder
    @OrderDate datetime,
    @DeliveryAddress varchar(100),
    @ItemsTVP OrderInfo READONLY,
    @OrderID int
AS

SET NOCOUNT, XACT_ABORT ON;  -- must have XACT_ABORT if using transaction

BEGIN TRAN;

UPDATE p
SET p.QtyInStock -= i.Quantity
FROM @OrderTVP i
JOIN Products p ON p.ProductID = i.ProductID;

INSERT Orders (OrderID, OrderDate, DeliveryAddress)
VALUES (@OrderID, @OrderDate, @DeliveryAddress);

SET @OrderID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

INSERT OrderDetails (ProductID, QtyOrdered, CurrentPrice)
SELECT i.ProductID, i.Quantity, p.CurrentPrice
FROM @OrderTVP i
JOIN Products p ON p.ProductID = i.ProductID;

COMMIT;
```

You use it like this

```sql
DECLARE @tvp dbo.OrderInfo;

INSERT @tvp (ProductID, Quantity)
VALUES (1, 5), (2, 4);

EXEC InsertOrder
    @OrderDate = '2022-01-01 09:02:32.232',
    @DeliveryAddress = 'Delivery Address: 1 Smith St, Melbourne',
    @ItemsTVP = @tvp,
    @OrderID = 123;
```

A real-life system would probably keep track of `AvailableQuantity` as well as `ActualQuantity`, and therefore you could see how much stock is held for live orders and whether you have oversold.

Comment: I agree with @allmhuran. For a job interview we should not be providing a complete answer. Moreover the question states that OrderId is an input parameter to the procedure.  Whilst it may be more natural for it to be an `IDENTITY `,  given the parameter on balance we should assume that it is not. The OP also wanted to pass a full date and time, so @OrderDate should be `datetime`. Finally, in a real life situation,  you would probably check that post update no qtyinstock was below 0, before proceeding.